# Which directives are allowed to have multiple declarations under same contex in Nginx config

Tags: nginx

the question is on the title.
So far I know that `server` and `location` directive can be declared more than one time under the same context. How about other directives? Thank you for your time!

Comment: [The manual](http://nginx.org/en/docs/dirindex.html) is the best place to go. Is there a specific problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Yes I did use it. But it does not specify which directive can be repeated.
I am trying to re-implement a program that works like NGINX, which gets input a config file. So I need to know which kind of structure in the config file is valid.

Comment: @DanilaVershinin: I've never said `server_name`. I said `server`, which can be repeated under `http` context.